# instance.save() method not updating the instance in the database

Tags: django, database, sqlite, model

I have written this code for product checkout. I wanted to create a Order model and then update the transaction ID. But it's not getting updated, doesn't even providing any error. Whats's the issue ?

```
@csrf_exempt
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_authenticated and not u.is_analyst)
def processOrder(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    transaction_id = datetime.now().timestamp()
    print(int(transaction_id))
    

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            customer=customer, complete=False)
        total = int(data['form']['total'])
  

        try:
            order.transaction_id = int(transaction_id)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
       
        order.complete = True
        print(order.transaction_id)
        try:
            order.save() 
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Here is my Order model that I've used.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_ordered = models.DateField(default="2014-02-20")
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    @property
    def shipping(self):
        shipping = False
        order_items = self.orderitem_set.all()
        for i in order_items:
            shipping = True
        return shipping

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        order_items = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in order_items])
        return total

    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        order_items = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in order_items])
        return total

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.id)
```

Comment: Is the order created? Maybe your method does't enter code inside `if`

Comment: Yeah it's created.

Comment: Maybe the user is not passing the test? The code looks alright to me

Comment: Is it maybe trying to  return multiple orders?  Without using a unique transaction id in this query, you could have multiple

Comment: It's creating two instances, First one is now taking the transaction id and then creates another one with same customer. Then when the customer order again, the previous one get's overwritten. I don't know why there's an extra instance getting created.